# getElementById returns undefined after dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

`getElementById` returns undefined. While i run it after Dom has been loaded.

This is my current code. I also tried running the function from the console window.

I tried calling the function with `window.onload` in the body.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
function test () {
    var element = getElementById("testing");

    element.innerHTML+= "<br/>Yeah!";
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="testing">
        I JUST love to test!
    </p>

<script>window.onload=test();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `document.getElementById(...)`?

Comment: yea forgot the document first..

Comment: `document.getElementById` *never* returns `undefined`. Either a DOM element or `null`.

Comment: Since the `<script>` is in the end of the body, you don't need to wait for `onload` - the elements are already loaded into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var element = document.getElementById("testing");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function and setting `window.onload` to the result of the function,
it should be :

```
<script>window.onload=test;</script>
```

Also, you *should* clean up the code, example :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        function test () {
            var element = document.getElementById("testing"); //document. NOT just getElementById
            element.innerHTML+= "<br/>Yeah!";
        }
        window.onload = test;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="testing">
        I JUST love to test!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: \@OneOfOne Was that really necessary...?

Comment: Was what necessary? I'm not the one that edited the question and every answer on the page 3 times.

Comment: All Chris was doing is improving the answers, which is encouraged. (also, you probably shouldn't insult anyone (especially a moderator) on this site if you don't want to be suspended)

Comment: My comment was harsh, however he didn't improve anything, he edited it because he didn't like it, which is abuse if you ask me.

Comment: I would have done the same, and I'm sure many others would too. (this is a pointless off topic discussion so I'll stop commenting now)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `document` there. `getElementById` is a method of `document`!

```
var element = document.getElementById("testing");
```

Also, as just mentioned by another answer, you are calling and defining the `test` function at the same time.

Should be like this:

```
window.onload = test;
```

Hope this helps!